# Database Changelog Design

Tags: python, database

I want to write a changelog system, so that when data is changed in a database, I can track the item that was changed, when it was changed, and the person that changed it in a user friendly way presented in a GUI. Ideally with pre-change data, post-change, data, add, update, delete etc.

Is there a name for what I'm trying to achieve? In the sense that if I was trying to figure out algorithms I could google Big O Notation, is there a phrase for what I'm trying to write?

```
+----------+--------+
|          | Apples |
+----------+--------+
| Player 1 | 10     |
| Player 2 | 20     |
| Player 3 | 30     |
+----------+--------+
```

- Currently I'm using the system below but wondering if I'm re-inventing the wheel.
- The changelog below would be generated if an admin updated Player 1's Apple count to 40.

```
Time: now()
User: admin
Operation: Edit
Row_Key: Player 1
Column_Key: Apples
Value: 40
```

Comment: Are you trying to describe [event sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah thanks I think that's what I'm trying to do